# Using different xml in same layouts in recycler-view viewholder

Tags: android

I have Multiple XML files in Layout folder  which is of multiple dots in a line, How can I set specific layout for specific position/stops in a particular layout in recycler-view Viewholder

Please Refer the

[image]

while the flight is in nonstop I can use them 
[image: this]

layout, if my flight is of two stops I can use 
[image: this] layout

Comment: What I have understood from your question that instead of text you want to display images for non-stop, one stop and two stops. right?

Comment: no i am using the layouts already but it not showing

Comment: then i did not understand your question correctly, please try to explain a little bit

Comment: when i inflate  respective xmls in the layout its only inflates 0 th position layout allover recyclerview

Comment: Wait let me explain

Comment: well if the flight is NON stop the adapter should be intelligent enough to add image One else it should add imageTwo! right?

Comment: I have 5 xml files naming  no_dot.xml, one_dot.xml, two_dot.xml, three_dot.xml etc. when i try to set these xml file in to a layout in side a adapter according the number of stops i get from server its only inflates the layout of 0th position's "stops".

Comment: @Rizwanatta You are Absolutely right ...But i don't want to set images ,what i want is a way to set layouts instead of images .

Comment: ok lemme edit the answer for that!

Comment: In your view holder class set image `one` or `two` based on flight stop condition. You don't need to use separate layout xml for separate stop condition. Just set image on respectively based on stop condition.

Comment: using images i find the quality degrades ...besides i don't have a designer team

Comment: Share your adapter class here

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the help check the official DOC [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand)

/// if you are not using the images you want to use two layout files in the design well that is very simple then! actually

just make a View any one you like lets say you have a linear layout there! and you want to load a view inside based on your condition then you can do it like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeVuHolder holder, int position) {
    //now all incoming data from the server needed to be


    item = listData.get(position);


    String FlightType = item.getFlightType();

    if (FlightType.equals("1")) {
       View itemInfo1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item1, holder.flatTypeContainer, true);


    } else if (FlightType.equals("2")) {
        View itemInfo2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item2, holder.flatTypeContainer, true);

    }
}
```

in the Viewholder class you can do this as this is

```
public class HomeVuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout flatTypeContainer;
        //...... other views

        public HomeVuHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            filghtTypeImageView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flatTypeContainer);

        }

}
```

This helped me once with images too! images are a little easy in your case though! ^_^

In the bindViewholder method of your recyclerView constructor you have to get the image either its from local resource or from any server online ! here is the example how to do it for a sample from local app resources!

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeVuHolder holder, int position) {
    //now all incoming data from the server needed to be
    //tightly bound here on the recycler View will be here

    item = listData.get(position);

    String FlightType = item.getFlightType();
    if (PostStatuses.equals("1")) {
        holder.filghtTypeImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_worker_green_24dp));
    } else if (PostStatuses.equals("2")) {
        holder.filghtTypeImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonStopImage));

    }
}
```

The View holder class would be something like this

```
public class HomeVuHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView filghtTypeImageView;
        //...... other views

        public HomeVuHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            filghtTypeImageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.flightTypeImage);

        }

}
```

for the image from server storage you can just simply use Glide or Picasso for the image To load in imageView onBindViewHolder

Comment: i don't want use images , what i want is a way to set layouts instead of images